# Why is the dictionary returning None when using the function, while it returns what I want inside that function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to write some program to manage "inventory".
I have come with a way to change list to dictionary, it adds up the values but returns None in the end.
The code looks like this:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    backpack = {}
    for i in addedItems:
        backpack.setdefault(i, 0)
        backpack[i] += 1
        print(backpack)
    for k, v in backpack.items():
        if k not in inventory.keys():
            inventory.setdefault(k, v)
        elif k in inventory.keys():
            inventory[k] += backpack[k]
    print(inventory)


inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
print(inv)
```

The print(inventory) returns what I want, but print(inv) returns None.
Can you help me understand what I do wrong?
Sorry if this is trivial.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are *printing* the inventory, not *returning* it. (Also, you are modifying the inventory argument in place, so there's no need to return it.)

Comment: Thank you for explaining such basics, I think I understand it now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    backpack = {}
    for i in addedItems:
        backpack.setdefault(i, 0)
        backpack[i] += 1
        print(backpack)
    for k, v in backpack.items():
        if k not in inventory.keys():
            inventory.setdefault(k, v)
        elif k in inventory.keys():
            inventory[k] += backpack[k]
    print(inventory)
    return inventory # This was missing!!


inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
print(inv)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, back to basics.

Comment: Adding a little bit of explanation about the cause of the problem to your answer, rather than just having code with a single comment, would make it more helpful—if not for the OP, then others who may not have encountered this problem before.

Comment: In this case it was a simple miss-out,, which the author of the question got straight away. Funny to get a negative score for the answer which was accepted to close the issue.